# Я сделал код и там постоянно идет ошибка проверил в других вопросах и сделал что там отвечали люди все равно проблема

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня ошибка на discord.py:
Сама ошибка:
`IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`
Код:

```
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True , administrator=True)
async def unban(self, ctx, userid: int, reason='Не уаазано'):
        user = await self.bot.fetch_user(userid)
        try:
            emd = discord.Embed(title="Возвращение с бана", description="Пользователь разбанен!",color=random.randint(000000,999999))
            await ctx.send( embed= emd)
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            return 
        except:
            return await ctx.send(f"Он не забанен!", delete_after=5)
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: В тексте ошибки написано про лишний отступ. Вас не смущает, что у вас лишний отступ у всех строк, которые находятся в теле функции `unban`?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, если вы пишите команду в когах, у Вас либо **нет** либо вы не **вставили** в приведенный Вами код строку:

```
@commands.command()
```

Далее, у Вас `no logic` строка:

```
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True , administrator=True)
```

Зачем здесь проверка и на возможность **выдачи бана** и на права **администратора**?

Во-вторых, ошибка говорит, что у Вас имеются отступы в коде. Попробуйте их убрать:

```
async def unban(self, ctx, userid: int, reason='Не уаазано'):
    user = await self.bot.fetch_user(userid)
    try:
        emd = discord.Embed(title="Возвращение с бана", description="Пользователь разбанен!",color=random.randint(000000,999999))
        await ctx.send(embed= emd)
        await ctx.guild.unban(user)
        return 
    except:
        return await ctx.send(f"Он не забанен!", delete_after=5)
```

Comment: Сообщите если вы не используете **cogs**. Я отредактирую ответ.

Comment: Вообще я не люблю cogs и не использую их

Comment: Тогда уберите `self` везде. Её используют в когах.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь